# Replace all images in HTML with text

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I am trying to replace all images in some HTML which meet specific requirements with the appropriate text.  The specific requirements are that they are of class "replaceMe" and the image src filename is in $myArray.  Upon searching for solutions, it appears that some sort of PHP DOM technique is appropriate, however, I am very new with this.  For instance, given $html, I wish to return $desired_html.  At the bottom of this post is my attempted implementation which currently doesn't work. Thank you

```
$myArray=array(
    'goodImgage1'=>'Replacement for Good Image 1',
    'goodImgage2'=>'Replacement for Good Image 2'
);

$html = '<div>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage1.png" alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage2.png" alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage2.png" alt="" class="dontReplaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="badImgage1.png"  alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
</div>';

$desiredHtml = '<div>
<p>Random text and an Replacement for Good Image 1.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an Replacement for Good Image 2.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage2.png" alt="" class="dontReplaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="badImgage1.png"  alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
</div>';
```

Below is what I am attempting to do..

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   //Temorarily disable errors resulting from improperly formed HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

//What does this do for me?
$imgs= $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img){}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query( '//img') as $img) {
    if(true){   //How do I check class and image name?
        $new = $doc->createTextNode("New Attribute"); 
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($new,$img);
    }
}

$html=$doc->saveHTML();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Comment: I think this will be much easier if u just replace them with preg_replace() or str_replace() or using preg_match() or strpos !== false ... as u have kind of a pattern anyway - go for regex maybe

Comment: @F.Müller  I've gotten mixed messages, and some seem to advocate using some sort of DOM techniques.

Comment: first filter $html by using preg_match_all() - filter the "replaceMe" (only these are relevant) - secondly loop this resulting array - then check if the image is ok or not (e.g. src attribute contains "good/bad") - you are done.

Comment: @F.Müller Trying regex tips on DOM issues is usually a way into eternal pain and agony. I speak from experience. See my upcoming answer, it's not that hard.

Comment: @likeitlikeit well as a rule yes, but this one ... - however you know how to deal with it - the better :)

Comment: @F.Müller If you generated the HTML yourself and can say for sure that it's always `src`, `alt`, then `class`, you might be fine with regex. However, have a look at how easily this is done with DOM and XPath. It's much cleaner, and also, in my humble opinion, more cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this, you were on a good way:

```
$myArray=array(
    'goodImgage1.png'=>'Replacement for Good Image 1',
    'goodImgage2.png'=>'Replacement for Good Image 2'
);

$html = '<div>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage1.png" alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage2.png" alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="goodImgage2.png" alt="" class="dontReplaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
<p>Random text and an <img src="badImgage1.png"  alt="" class="replaceMe">.  More random text.</p>
</div>';

$classesToReplace = array('replaceMe');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   //Temorarily disable errors resulting from improperly formed HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query( '//img') as $img) {
    // get the classes into an array
    $classes = explode(' ', $img->getAttribute('class')); // this will contain the classes assigned to the element
    $classMatches = array_intersect($classes, $classesToReplace);

    // preprocess the image name to match the $myArray keys
    $imageName = $img->getAttribute('src');

    if (isset($myArray[$imageName]) && $classMatches) {   
        $new = $doc->createTextNode($myArray[$imageName]); 
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($new,$img);
    }
}

echo var_dump($html = $doc->saveHTML());
```

Please note the following:

- I made the code check for images that have the `replaceMe` class, potentially in addition to other classes
- I added the full image file names to your `$myArray` keys, basically for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks likeitlikeit,  I will need to spend a little going through your solution, but it seems like it will work.

Comment: Actually, didn't need to take much time!  Was just missing the getAttribute() method.  Thanks

Comment: Enjoyed it. Maybe it helped F.Müller as well :)

Answer (score 1):

`likeitlikeit` was faster. I'll post my answer, though, because it has some differences in detail, e.g. `xpath` doing the job of selecting only `<img>` with the appropriate `class` attribute, use of `pathinfo` to get filename without extension.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($h); // assume HTML in $h

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img[@class = 'replaceMe']");

foreach ($imgs as $img) {

    $imgfile = pathinfo($img->getAttribute("src"),PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    if (array_key_exists($imgfile, $myArray)) { 

        $replacement = $doc->createTextNode($myArray[$imgfile]);
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $img); 
    }
}

echo "<pre>" . htmlentities($doc->saveHTML()) . "</pre>";
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/11XZt7

Comment: Thanks Michi,  While faster is good, simplicity is often better.