# preg_match() not working in some cases

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I feel like this should be such an easy 'change the comma', so I've done my research and tried many different things, but nothing seems to work. First the code I used to attempt to debug it:

```
/* More code before */

$Test = "This is a test <ul>TEST</ul> Blabla";
$Real = $Data['chapters']['introduction'];
var_dump($Real);
echo "\n\n";

preg_match('/<ul>(.*)<\/ul>/', $Test, $VarTest);
var_dump($VarTest);
echo "\n\n";

preg_match('/<ul>(.*)<\/ul>/', $Real, $VarReal);
var_dump($VarReal);
```

The result is this:

```
string(1888) "<p>The <b>theory of relativity</b>, or simply <b>relativity</b>, generally encompasses two theories of <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein" title="Albert Einstein">Albert Einstein</a>: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity" title="Special relativity">special relativity</a> and <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity" title="General relativity">general relativity</a>. Concepts introduced by the theories of relativity include:</p>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Measurements of various quantities are <i>relative</i> to the velocities of observers. In particular, space and time can <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation" title="Time dilation">dilate</a>.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime" title="Spacetime">Spacetime</a>: space and time should be considered together and in relation to each other.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>The speed of light is nonetheless invariant, the same for all observers.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>The term &quot;theory of relativity&quot; was based on the expression &quot;relative theory&quot; (<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language" title="German language">German</a>: <span lang="de"><i>Relativtheorie</i></span>) used by <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Planck" title="Max Planck">Max Planck</a> in 1906, who emphasized how the theory uses the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity" title="Principle of relativity">principle of relativity</a>. In the discussion section of the same paper <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Bucherer" title="Alfred Bucherer">Alfred Bucherer</a> used for the first time the expression &quot;theory of relativity&quot; (<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language" title="German language">German</a>: <span lang="de"><i>Relativit&auml;tstheorie</i></span>).</p>
"

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "<ul>TEST</ul>"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "TEST"
}


array(0) {
}
```

**Any idea on why the last array is empty (when it should contain the 3 list elements)?**

Some more info, it is retrieved from a MySQL using PDO, I've tried escaping it (for the quotes), replacing the quotes, checked that this text size is way below the preg_match() string limit, I just cannot find where the problem is. I think the code speaks for itself about where specifically the problem is, anyway, I'd gladly perform the tests you need. Thanks.

Comment: This is the [third time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16638700/1553481) that people try to use regex on HTML tonight. Please please please don't. It's so easy otherwise.

Comment: @likeitlikeit , I try to learn from people more experienced than myself, so I'll check PHP's DOMDocument class as Spudley suggested

Comment: Sorry if I came over as discouraging. Go ahead and check DOMDocument and XPath. They're really the right tool to do something like you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem you have here is that you are trying to parse HTML code using regex. Even if you can get it to work with the data you have, as soon as the data contains nested `<ul>` tags, your regex will blow up, and at that point it will become extremely difficult to get it working. Parsing HTML really ought to be done using a DOM parser (ie PHP's DOMDocument class). Regex is the wrong tool for the job.

That said, if you *must* do it with regex, you need to use the `s` modifier, due to the input being across multiple lines. This modifier changes the behaviour of the dot character in the regex so that it includes line feed characters.

So your final pattern needs to look like this:

```
preg_match('/<ul>(.*)<\/ul>/s', $Real, $VarReal);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Now that you mention this, I remember reading once long time ago something similar to that, the problem being `<ul><ul></ul></ul>` being recognised as only 1 `ul` tag. I'll check DOMDocument, meanwhile, you answered perfectly my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex in the second case is multiline.  Append “m” to your function call:

```
preg_match('/<ul>(.*)<\/ul>/m', $Real, $VarReal);
```

Comment: It was really similar, just adding 's' instead of 'm'.

Answer (score 1):

I used the code I had from modifying some SO answers a little bit; But I found the solution by checking some other answers and seeing Patrice Levesque's one. I used 's' to the function call, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5699911/938236):

```
preg_match('/<ul>(.*)<\/ul>/s', $Real, $VarReal);
```

Comment: ah, it looks like you found the answer while I was typing it. but i'll leave my answer in place as the DOM parser vs regex point is an important one to bear in mind.

Comment: And I accepted yours since for the 1 minute something of difference between yours and mine, yours seems legit (;